# MediaWiki LocalSettings.php $wgSiteName issue

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, config

So I have the wiki exactly as I want it but the sitename variable always reverts to lowercase...

I assume there is a special character maybe..like in c# you have \t or \n to format text but I cannot find anything of the sort..

THis is directly from the wikipage describing sitename

"Site name
The $wgSitename variable holds the name of your wiki setup. This name gets included many times throughout the system, such as via MediaWiki:Pagetitle. For instance, the Wikipedia tagline "'From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia."' makes use of this setting."

It states that wikipedia uses sitename to title its site as .... 'From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.'

They have multiple capital letters

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the sitename reverting to lowercase?  Is this in the title of the browser window or on a wiki page somewhere?

Comment: It is the title of the site at the top that you see on any page on the wiki.

Comment: You mean the actual text "From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia" text?

Comment: yes, on mediawiki wiki it says that its set in the above wgSitename value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That text actually comes from the page [MediaWiki:Tagline](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTagline_%28Site_Subtitle%29). Edit that page on your wiki and you can make that line say anything you want. You also have to edit MediaWiki:Common.css like it says in that link to make the tagline show up on pages.